# Making parallel requests from within Springboot + Webflux

Tags: reactive-programming

I'm playing around with Springboot 2 with the webflux stack.

Within the application I'm looking to make multiple HTTP requests in parallel to downstream services to reduce the overall response time back to the client. Is this possible without playing around with threads?

I'm currently using `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient` but open to other clients that would support this; or even RXJava.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to achieve it by something like below. It's a naive example but the async/http requests are made in `downstream.request1()` and `downstream.request2()`. If is a more elegant way to achieve this I'd be interested.

```
@GetMapping("/sample")
public Mono<String> getMultipleRequests() {
    Mono<String> monoResponse1 = downstream.request1();
    Mono<String> monoResponse2 = downstream.request2();

    return Mono.zip(monoResponse1, monoResponse2)
        .flatMap(a -> myTransform(a));
}

private Mono<String> myTransform(Tuple2<String, String> tuple) {
    String t1 = tuple.getT1();
    String t2 = tuple.getT2();
    return Mono.just(t1 + t2);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `flatMap` you should use `map`. There's really no reason to create a new stream. In this example you could save a few characters with `return monoResponse1.zipWith(monoResponse2, this::myTransform)`.